# How to render json as elements in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dynamic table where I am displaying some data, the 90 % of this data is just text, but the 10 % are elements. As you see below, there is a table with some json attached. For example, where the json says `"element_type": ["WAGER_ACTION_BUTTON"]` I need to display a button, and in the other case, there says `...:"BASIC_CHECKBOX"` then I need to display a checkbox.

so, the header of the table says `FILL OPEN`, that means that there I need to display a button. See at the bottom the json object

[image]

here is the table

```
  <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in cols"
                ng-init="isXX = column.indexOf('XX') === 0">
              <span ng-if="isXX">{{column.substring(3).replace('_', ' ')}}</span>
              <span ng-if="!isXX">{{column}}</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td ng-repeat="column in cols">
              <span>{{row[column]}}</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and here the code in the Angular Part

```
    ReportsFactory.pendingBets(reportParam).then(function(data) {
      if (data.length) {
        gridInfo = _.forEach(data, function(item) {return item;});
        $scope.rows = gridInfo;
        $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.rows[0]);
      }
    }
```

here is the json object I am receiving from the backend

```
  {
    "BET": 57630343,
    "CUSTOMER": 181645,
    "SPORT": "MLB",
    "XX_FILL OPEN": {
      "element": {
        "element_type": [
          "WAGER_ACTION_BUTTON"
        ],
        "element_call": [
          "fillOpen(57630343)"
        ],
        "element_content": [
          ""
        ]
      }
    },
    "XX_VIEW": null,
    "XX_CANCEL": {
      "element": {
        "element_type": [
          "BASIC_CHECKBOX"
        ],
        "element_call": [
          ""
        ],
        "element_content": [
          "0"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

so everytime you see a prop starting with `XX_`, means an element.

In this json you see above, the object keys: BET, CUSTOMER, SPORT, XX_FILL_OPEN, XX_VIEW and XX_CANCEL, are the headers of the table, I repeat my self here: everytime a prop comes with `XX_` at the beginning, that should be an element, but I need to figure out what kind of element is, in order to display it in the DOM.

Comment: i prefer to make directive for form elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would create a custom directive.
2. pass the element portion of the json object to the directive through isolate    scope.
3. Have the link function create the new element
4. Insert the new element via transclude

   Another solution is just to use a switch statement via ngSwitch
   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

given the data you have above there is a couple ways you could switch on it you  could just switch on the cols value or you could switch on the element type in the rows object. Here is an example of both approaches

http://embed.plnkr.co/ySJeKeC95rIp4LZCxl68/preview

Note that is also possible to switch on keys of arrays and objects as well as the values but use this syntax in ng-repeat instead.

```
//to switch on value 
<div  ng-repeat="(key, value) in bars">
    <div ng-switch ="value">
        <button ng-switch-when="foo" >foo Button</button>
         <input  ng-switch-when="bas" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
</div>

//to switch on key 
<div  ng-repeat="(key, value) in bars">
    <div ng-switch ="key">
        <button ng-switch-when="foo" >foo Button</button>
         <input  ng-switch-when="bas" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I use this ng-switch based on the json I post in my question ?

Comment: around 3 or 4 as a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of "column" and use either an ng-switch (if column names are all known) or an ng-if.
If i understood correctly, here are two implementations:

With ng-switch:

```
<div ng-switch="column">
    <button ng-switch-when="XX_FILL OPEN" >Test Button</button>
    <input ng-switch-when="XX_CANCEL" type="checkbox" />
    <span ng-switch-default>{{row[column]}}</span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/16L31dmm/2/

With ng-if:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in cols">
    <span ng-if="column.indexOf('XX') < 0">{{row[column]}}</span>
    <button ng-if="column.indexOf('FILL OPEN') >= 0" >Test Button</button>
    <input ng-if="column.indexOf('CANCEL') >= 0" type="checkbox" />
</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/16L31dmm/3/